# Script to open a bunch of browser tabs, based on data from an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, ruby, excel, scripting, automation

Take for example a link format of:

```
www.stackoverflow.com/xxxxxxx
```

I have an Excel spreadsheet with one of the columns as a bunch of these `xxxxxx` values. I need to pull all of them from the spreadsheet and open them as new tabs on my browser. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I've never really scripted before but I am more than willing to learn if it is necessary.

Comment: Which platform? On Linux it's pretty easy...

Comment: There are two parts to this. The second part (opening the links in the browser) is easy—see TJD's answer for the Python version. The first part, getting the links out of Excel, is also easy, but the answer depends on a variety of different questions. Do you have to extract it from a live Excel process, or a file? If the latter, can you save the file in .csv format? Are you using Python or Ruby? Are you on Mac on Windows? Can you install additional modules via pip or gem or are you trying to distribute something?

Comment: Greasemonkey is not the best tool for this and couldn't fully automate the process.  Pretty sure you can write an Excel macro that will open the web pages for you, though.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I agree, Excel is the direct path. A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=excel+open+url) turned up lots of hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, use the `webbrowser` module to open a browser tab once you've extracted the URL.

For reading the URLs, you should either open your spreadsheet in Excel and save it in CSV format, which you can read with the `csv` module; or install the python module `xlrd` which can read real Excel spreadsheets. Assuming you install `xlrd`, you can extract the URLs and open them in tabs like this:

```
import xlrd, webbrowser

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('websites.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# Suppose your URLs are in column 5, rows 2 to 30
url_column = 5
for row in range(2, 31):
    url = sheet.cell_value(row, url_column)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

**Update:** I now recommend [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) over `xlrd`/`xlwt` for working with Excel documents. It can read and write `xlsx` files, for example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'my_document.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
print(sheet['D18'].value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on doing more elaborate things with the tabs after they are open, I would recommend looking at browser automation tools that use a python framework.

I would recommend [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) webdriver. It's super easy to use as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python `webbrowser` module

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.stackoverflow.com')
webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.stackoverflow.com/xxxx')
```

Parsing your CSV file to get the strings is trivial with standard string methods.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should dig into Ruby's [Win32OLE](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/index.html) automation library.
With it, you can do all sorts of automation jobs in Windows.